# Replace all selected characters inside the file

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program which swaps all letters inside a file, into different ones.
When i use more than line.replace, it writes the double amount of text.
Need efficient way to turn every single character into different ones.
Any ideas are appreciated.

```
import sys,os,time
f1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
f2 = open("test.encrypted", 'w')
for line in f1:
      f2.write(line.replace('a', '~'))  <--- Need more character lists to replace
      f2.write(line.replace('b', '~'))

f1.close()
f2.close()
print(f1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just alter your `line` variable first, and only write when you are done with your replacements:

```
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('a', '~')
    line = line.replace('b', '~')
    f2.write(line)
```

Note that now there is only *one* `.write()` call.

You can even chain the `.replace()` calls:

```
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('a', '~').replace('b', '~')
    f2.write(line)
```

For one-character replacements, you may want to consider the [`str.translate()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), combined with the [`string.maketrans()` helper function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

```
from string import maketrans

tilde_replace = maketrans('ab', '~' * 2)

for line in f1:
    line = line.translate(tilde_replace)
    f2.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform all of the substitutions at the same time using the [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) method that's built into strings. The [`string.maketrans()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) function takes two arguments, the first is a string listing the characters that you want to replace, and the second string (which must be the same length as the first one) shows the replacement character for the corresponding position in the first string.

```
>>> import string
>>> t = string.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba')
>>> s = 'this is a string that will get mixed up'
>>> s.translate(t)
'gsrh rh z hgirmt gszg droo tvg nrcvw fk'
```

...and then write that finished string out.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping dictionary that maps characters to their replacements:

**Demo:**

```
>>> dic = {'a':'~','b':'~'}
>>> strs = "abcd"
>>> strs = "".join([dic.get(c,c) for c in strs])
>>> strs
'~~cd'
```

Answer (score 0):

You write double the text because you are calling write() twice.  Try something like

```
newLine = line
newLine.replace('a', '~')
newLine.replace('b', '~')
f2.write(newLine)
```

Comment: Just do `line = line.replace(...)`. Don't mask a built-in by naming your variable `str`.

Comment: Careless mistake...I just wanted a new variable to emphasize the difference between the "old line" and "new line".  Fixed

Comment: Note that `replace` does not modify the string; you have to assign the result to some variable, like in Martijn's comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. You could do it this way.

```
source = 'test.txt'
dest = 'test.encrypted'
tbl = {'f': '~', 'o':'#', 'b': ';', 'a': '[', 'r': '$'}

open(dest, 'w').write(''.join([tbl.get(c, c) for c in open(source, 'r').read()]))
```

Which gives

```
foobar => ~##;[$
```

The `string.maketrans()` solution suggested by others is more elegant, though.